# Changing service method returned value using Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to change the returned value of a mock defined as `let userIdService: UserIdService;` to "anonymous" from the default value I have set at the start of the test "123" , however the returned value is always "123" in the test called `"test no points returned"`.It might be related somehow to ngOnInit and when to spy but not sure how.Here is the full code

```
import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, flush, inject, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthService, OCC_USER_ID_ANONYMOUS, UserIdService } from '@spartacus/core';
import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { PointsRetrievalService } from './points-retrieval.service';
import { CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent, CustomerPoints } from './user-points-interfaces/customer-points-interfaces';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UserpointsComponent } from './userpoints.component';


const anonymousUserId$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(
  OCC_USER_ID_ANONYMOUS
);

let POINTS = 30;
let ZERO_POINTS = 0;
let TITLE = "TITLE";
let HEADER_TEXT = "HEADER_TEXT"
let FOOTER_TEXT = "FOOTER_TEXT";
let CUSTOMER_ID = "123";
const customerPoints: CustomerPoints = { points: POINTS };

const customerPointsComponent: CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent =
{
  title: TITLE,
  headerText: HEADER_TEXT,
  footerText: FOOTER_TEXT
}

const MockCmsComponentData = <CmsComponentData<CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent>>{
  data$: of(customerPointsComponent),
  uid: CUSTOMER_ID,
};

class MockUserIdService implements Partial<UserIdService> {
  getUserId(): Observable<string> {
    return of(CUSTOMER_ID);
  }
}


describe('UserpointsComponent', () => {
  let component: UserpointsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserpointsComponent>;
  let userIdService: UserIdService;
  let mockAuthSerice = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthService', ['isUserLoggedIn']);
  mockAuthSerice.isUserLoggedIn.and.returnValue(
    of(true)
  );
  const pointsRetrievalService = jasmine.createSpyObj<PointsRetrievalService>(['getPointsForCustomerId']);
  pointsRetrievalService.getPointsForCustomerId.and.returnValue(of(customerPoints))



  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),

      ],
      declarations: [UserpointsComponent],
      providers:
        [
          {
            provide: CmsComponentData,
            useValue: MockCmsComponentData,
          },
          { provide: PointsRetrievalService, useValue: pointsRetrievalService },
          { provide: AuthService, useValue: mockAuthSerice },
          { provide: UserIdService, useClass: MockUserIdService },
        ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
    userIdService = TestBed.inject(UserIdService);

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserpointsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockAuthSerice.isUserLoggedIn.calls.reset();
    pointsRetrievalService.getPointsForCustomerId.calls.reset();
  });



  it("test no points returned", () => {
    //this is ignored
    spyOn(userIdService, 'getUserId').and.returnValue(of(OCC_USER_ID_ANONYMOUS));

    const title = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p')).nativeElement;
    const pointsMessage = FOOTER_TEXT + " "
    expect(title.innerHTML).toBe(pointsMessage);
  });



});
```

here is the component code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService, CmsComponent, OCC_USER_ID_ANONYMOUS, User, UserIdService, UserService, } from '@spartacus/core';
import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PointsRetrievalService } from './points-retrieval.service';

import { CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent, CustomerPoints } from './user-points-interfaces/customer-points-interfaces';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-userpoints',
  templateUrl: './userpoints.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userpoints.component.scss']
})
export class UserpointsComponent implements OnInit {

  ZERO_CUSTOMER_POINTS: CustomerPoints = { points: 0 };
  data$: Observable<CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent> = this.component.data$;
  customerPoints$!: Observable<number | undefined>;
  constructor(
    public component: CmsComponentData<CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent>, private pointsRetrievalService: PointsRetrievalService,
    protected auth: AuthService,
    protected userIdService: UserIdService,
    protected customerUserService: UserService
  ) {
  }

  public getCustomerPoints(): Observable<number | undefined> {
    return this.customerPoints$;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initCustomerPoints()


  }

  get headerText$(): Observable<string> {

    return this.component.data$.pipe((map((data) => data?.headerText
    )));
  }

  getHeaderText(): Observable<string> {
    return this.headerText$;
  }


  get footerText$(): Observable<string> {
    return this.component.data$.pipe((map((data) => data?.footerText
    )));
  }

  getFooterText(): Observable<string> {
    return this.footerText$;
  }





  initCustomerPoints() {
    this.data$ = this.component.data$;
    this.customerPoints$ = this.auth
      .isUserLoggedIn()
      .pipe(

        switchMap(() =>
          this.userIdService.getUserId()
        ),
        switchMap((user: string) => {
          console.log("USER IS :" + user);
          if (user) {
            if (user === OCC_USER_ID_ANONYMOUS) {
              return of(this.ZERO_CUSTOMER_POINTS)
            }
            return this.pointsRetrievalService.getPointsForCustomerId(
              user
            );
          }
          else {
            return of(undefined);
          }

        }),

        map((userPoints: CustomerPoints | undefined) =>
          userPoints?.points)
      )

  }


}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <ng-container *ngIf="customerPoints$ | async as customerPoints">
        <h2>{{headerText$ | async }}</h2>
        <p>{{footerText$ | async }} {{customerPoints}}</p> 

  </ng-container>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, you can call `ngOnInit` again, and it should hopefully work.

```
it("test no points returned", () => {
    //this is ignored
    spyOn(userIdService, 'getUserId').and.returnValue(of(OCC_USER_ID_ANONYMOUS));
    
    // call ngOnInit again
    component.ngOnInit();
    const title = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p')).nativeElement;
    const pointsMessage = FOOTER_TEXT + " "
    expect(title.innerHTML).toBe(pointsMessage);
  });
```

The first `fixture.detectChanges()` you call, is when `ngOnInit()` is called so you can also mock before this `fixture.detectChanges()`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserpointsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // !! spy here
    spyOn(userIdService, 'getUserId').and.returnValue(of(OCC_USER_ID_ANONYMOUS));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```